# Custom Authorize Attribute being called even if attribute has not being used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having the following issue with ASP.Net MVC 5. The OnAuthorization method is being called even though I haven't added the attribute anywhere in my code.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

        }
    }
```

I added the filter under Global.asax:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
```

Shouldn't the OnAuthorization method be called only when the attribute is added to a class or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't the OnAuthorization method be called only when the attribute
>   is added to a class or method?

Partially yes. But you need to know that ASP.Net MVC has a notion of global filters. Global filters are used when you don't need to repeat yourself (breaking DRY principle). It helps you to centralize and configure filters that need to be executed for all controllers.

This line

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
```

is adding the filter globally so it is normal it is called even if you don't apply the filter attribute to your controller class or action.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work in a way that only gets executed when added to a specific class or method?

Comment: So just remove this line => `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());`

Comment: As easy as that :). Thank you sir!!